# Excel 2013 power view export to PDF/XPS shows only the first page

Tags: excel, pdf, export

I exported (using File->Export->Create PDF/XPS Document) a multi page Excel 2013 power view report to PDF and I see only the first page in PDF. It looks as though print screen of the first page exported into PDF. Doing the same using VBS or Export to XPS also shows similar behaviour.

Appreciate any suggestions/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

To close the thread, this is the "by design" feature of power view. So be careful if you rely on power view export feature. Details at technet [site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231522.aspx).

Comment: Any workaround to print/export all data of Power View report?